# How can we improve the [proofing] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [proofing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofing) that has no wiki and only 4 questions. 3 out of 4 questions are about preventing pets from chewing on wires.

If we want to keep this tag (personally I think we should remove it), is there something we can do to make it more useful? Preferably renaming it to something a bit more descriptive (maybe [house-proofing]?).

Otherwise, it seems to me like we could use the tag for other questions that might not have been the intent when the tag was created.

For example:

[How to keep my dog from urinating in specific places?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/how-to-keep-my-dog-from-urinating-in-specific-places?s=1|0.4543)

[How can I prevent my puppy from chewing on objects?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/how-can-i-prevent-my-puppy-from-chewing-on-objects)

[How do I keep my neighbor's cat from defecating in my yard?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/how-do-i-keep-my-neighbors-cat-from-defecating-in-my-yard)

[How can I keep my cat from climbing on my desk?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-from-climbing-on-my-desk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the tag from the 4 questions, and replaced it with [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) on the ones that didn't already have it.

For reference, the questions were:

[What can I do to prevent/educate a kitten from chewing wires?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-educate-a-kitten-from-chewing-wires)

[Make wires unpalatable?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5987/make-wires-unpalatable)

[How do you bunny proof behind the couch?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/how-do-you-bunny-proof-behind-the-couch)

[How can I prevent my ferrets from chewing on wires?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/how-can-i-prevent-my-ferrets-from-chewing-on-wires)

I'd be game for re-adding the tag, or a similar one, if we could get more questions using it.

Comment: The three about wires are "safety chewing".  I added to the couch one "safety containment" since that is what it's referring to.  I think proofing can stay dead.

Answer (score 1):

Kill the tag because it's not really possible to relate those 4 suggested questions; instead, replace it with the [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) (dance) tag, which has 65 questions.

Of the 4 questions currently tagged [proofing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofing), 3 are duplicates of each other (prevent animal X (rabbit, kitten, ferret) from chewing wires), and 1 is a semi-duplicate (prevent a rabbit from going behind the couch... ostensibly to chew wires!).